# Wrap text to a new line once maxWidth is reached in EaselJS

Tags: canvas, createjs, easeljs

I am new to EaselJS. I set the maxWidth property of a text to 200px and after the maximum width is reached, the text starts getting compressed. How to ensure that the text wraps to a new line after the max width is reached?

```
var text = new createjs.Text();
text.set({
text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elementum elit vitae nisl elementum, et aliquet quam malesuada. Pellentesque porta consequat pellentesque. Quisque vel molestie quam. Aliquam in vehicula magna. Integer ac congue sem, et tempor libero. Etiam pharetra, quam et posuere porta, lectus odio iaculis nibh, eget porttitor magna elit id felis. Mauris luctus lobortis tincidunt."
x: 0,
y: 0,
font: "16px Arial black",
maxWidth: 200
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`lineWidth`](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Text.html#property_lineWidth) instead of `maxWidth`. The `maxWidth` mirrors the default HTML Canvas behaviour of shrinking the text to fit, whereas the `lineWidth` will wrap the text to a new line.

```
var text = new createjs.Text().set({
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elementum elit vitae nisl elementum, et aliquet quam malesuada. Pellentesque porta consequat pellentesque. Quisque vel molestie quam. Aliquam in vehicula magna. Integer ac congue sem, et tempor libero. Etiam pharetra, quam et posuere porta, lectus odio iaculis nibh, eget porttitor magna elit id felis. Mauris luctus lobortis tincidunt.",
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    font: "16px Arial black",
    lineWidth: 200
});
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/sh0s6t30/

Comment: EaselJS is still one of the best libraries for canvas.. thanks Lanny! :)